# How do I compile assembly code?

Tags: assembly, x86

A good friend of mine found and gave me a book on intel 80x86 assembly coding.  One rather large fact that the books skips over is what program you should use to code with.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your platform, you may be interested in `gas`, `yasm`, `nasm`, or `masm`.  Most Linux systems should have one of the first three in their package management system, and the fourth, the Microsoft Macro Assembler, is free on the internet.

Answer (score 3):

[**PCASM**](http://www.drpaulcarter.com/pcasm/) is a free text book that you may wish to consider as a companion to your friend's book. It is written by Dr Carter, a university professor. It uses real code and teaches you how to compile with **NASM**. It also covers how to integrate with C/C++ libraries. Its a great book and teaches you some of the internals of C++ code. [**NASM**](http://www.nasm.us/) is a great way to go if you want portability.

In College I learned from Irvine's [**Intel Assembly Book**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013602212X). The book covers the [**MASM**](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=12654) compiler. I found this a little easier to learn from, unfortunately, the book is not free.

I would use **PCASM** as a companion book. Its fairly short and covers some interesting topics as I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the open source GNU Assembler: http://www.gnu.org/s/binutils/

Answer (score 1):

An open source alternative is the `flat assembler`, [FASM](http://flatassembler.net/).

Comment: Could perhaps someone enlighten me why it could be that I received two downvotes on this? If I made some sort of faux pas, I'll just repeat it if I don't know why.

Comment: Strangely I received the same two downvotes on my answer.  Probably was automated or malicious.